# MySQL find records within 15 minutes using two timestamps

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a query to find records on two tables that are within a certain time frame.  I've joined the two tables on the user_id -

```
ON a.USERID = SUBSTRING(b.USERNAME,2,8)
```

But I also need to find records by timestamp, there's a field on the first table - a.ANSWER_TIMESTAMP which denotes when a call was answered and a field on the second table - b.EnteredDateTime which denotes when a workorder was created.

I need to find records that were entered within 15 minutes or less(b.EnteredDateTime) than the a.ANSWER_TIMESTAMP field.

I've been playing with the following as part of the table join but seem to be bringing back results after the 15 minute timeframe I've specified -

```
AND b.EnteredDateTime >= DATE_ADD(a.ANSWER_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two conditions.  "within 15 minutes" is rather ambiguous, but something like this:

```
ON a.USERID = SUBSTRING(b.USERNAME,2,8) AND
   b.EnteredDateTime >= a.ANSWER_TIMESTAMP AND
   b.EnteredDateTime < DATE_ADD(a.ANSWER_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```